# Event Handling is not working for all controls in the asp.net web application

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, web-applications

Any button `Onclick` event is not working on my project. I inserted one more button called `button1` for testing if it works but found that it is not working by changing the text of a label. Unfortunately,  It is not working at all. Only page load event-driven is working.

I have solved the problem of button event handling by adding these attributes.
but when comes to other types of controls, these attributes cannot be included, so that problem is not solved.

```
<asp:Button ID="UpdateBtn" runat="server" OnClick="UpdateBtn_Click" Text="Button" CausesValidation="False" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

The problem is not solved with other controls. For example, after the user clicks on an update button, a function will be called that checks the value in the textbox and make some calculation.
After debugging, I found that the program cannot read any values from the textbox.

Note: I am using packages like bootstrap, Ajax as they are already built-in in the asp.net web forms web applications. I have also tried to exclude them from the project as mentioned in some references, however, nothing changed.

Comment: What other controls you are using? What events of those controls you are using? What issue you are facing with button click event?

Comment: as mentioned above: after the user clicks on an update button, a function will be called that checks the value in the textbox and make some calculation. After debugging, I found that the program cannot read any values from the textbox.

Comment: Can you share the HTML of the text boxes which you want to read? Also the code of button's click event? What values you are getting from textbox while debugging? Are you getting error?